# Why does it put in the values twice in the database?

Tags: php

I got a problem and I don't know where the problem comes from , my code :

```
<?php
session_start();
if( isset( $_POST["verzenden1"] ) )
{
    $Bestelling = "Gunsafe";
}
if( isset( $_POST["verzenden2"] ) )
{
    $Bestelling = "5-6 wapens(sleutel)";
}
if( isset( $_POST["verzenden3"] ) )
{
    $Bestelling = "5-6 wapens(toetsenbord)";
}
if( isset( $_POST["verzenden4"] ) )
{
    $Bestelling = "8-16 wapens(sleutel)";
}
if( isset( $_POST["verzenden5"] ) )
{
    $Bestelling = "8-16 wapens(toetsenbord)";
}
if( isset( $_POST["verzenden6"] ) )
{
    $Bestelling = "Pistoolkluis";
}
if( isset( $_POST["versturen"] ) )
{
    include 'Databankverbinden.php';

    $Bestelling1 = $_POST["Bestelling"];
    $Naam = $_POST["Naam"];
    $Adres = $_POST["Adres"];
    $Telefoon = $_POST["Telefoonnummer"];
    $Email = $_POST["Email"];
    if( isset( $_POST['Levering'] ) && $_POST['Levering'] == 'Ja' )
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO bestelling(Naam, Adres, Telefoon, Email, Bestelling, Levering) VALUES ('$Naam','$Adres','$Telefoon','$Email','$Bestelling1','1')";

        $result = mysql_query( $sql ) or die( 'query fout' );
        if( !filter_var( $Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) )
        {
            echo "<script>alert('E-mail is niet geldig!')</script>";
            echo "<script>document.location.href='Betaling.php'</script>";
        }
        else
        {
            $to = "titansafes@telenet.be";
            $subject = "Bestelling";
            $message = "De volgende persoon : $Naam \n Heeft besteld: $Bestelling1 \n Gegevens: \n Adres: $Adres \n Telefoon nummer : $Telefoon \n E-mail : $Email  \n Deze persoon zou graag zijn kluis geleverd zien.  ";
            $from = "$Email";
            $headers = "From:" . $from;
            mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
            echo "<script>alert('Uw bestelling is geplaatst , klik op home als u weg wilt gaan.');</script>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO bestelling(Naam, Adres, Telefoon, Email, Bestelling, Levering) VALUES ('$Naam','$Adres','$Telefoon','$Email','$Bestelling1','0')";
        $result = mysql_query( $sql ) or die( 'query fout' );
        if( !filter_var( $Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) )
        {
            echo "<script>alert('E-mail is niet geldig!')</script>";
            echo "<script>document.location.href='Betaling.php'</script>";
        }
        else
        {
            $to = "titansafes@telenet.be";
            $subject = "Bestelling";
            $message = "De volgende persoon : $Naam \n Heeft besteld: $Bestelling1 \n Gegevens: \n Adres: $Adres \n Telefoon nummer : $Telefoon \n E-mail : $Email \n Deze persoon zou graag zijn kluis komen afhalen.  ";
            $from = "$Email";
            $headers = "From:" . $from;
            mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
            echo "<script>alert('Uw bestelling is geplaatst , klik op home als u weg wilt gaan.');</script>";
        }
    }
    $result = mysql_query( $sql ) or die( 'query fout' );
    if( !filter_var( $Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) )
    {
        echo "<script>alert('E-mail is niet geldig!')</script>";
        echo "<script>document.location.href='Betaling.php'</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        $to = "$Email";
        $subject = "Bestelling";
        $message = "Beste klant \n U heeft een bestelling geplaatst op titansafes. U wordt binnenkort gecontacteerd over uw bestelling ($Bestelling1). \n Met vriendelijke Groeten \n Titansafes";
        $from = "titansafes@telenet.be";
        $headers = "From:" . $from;
        mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
    }
}
?>
```

It puts the values twice in the database , if the "levering" = 1 , it puts it in the database , but like this : [image] And also if the "levering" = 0 , the same : [image]
I don't get why it does that ....

Comment: Holy crap, so many nested `if`s...

Comment: They are not nested – it was just bad code formatting.

Comment: Hahaha yes indeed there are many if's in it :D And I'm sorry I am not a real pro into php , im just a kid going to school , and we do alot of trial and error on our school

Comment: @feeela lol, it was indented like they were nested.. :D

Comment: @Mr.Alien It’s actually not that much it’s just a weird indentation style.

Comment: Yep – now look what my IDE can do with a single stroke on my keyboard…

Comment: @Gumbo Yea I just realized that, at first glance, it seemed like it was nested :)

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at http://php.net/switch by the way.

Comment: @feeela May I know which IDE is that?

Comment: Please do not use the (deprecated) `mysql` API, switch to `mysqli` or `PDO` and start use `prepared statements`. Your code is very open to SQL-Injections!

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have the below code on *Line (66)*

```
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die('query fout');
```

This executes your SQL once more.

Comment: Indeed this is the mistake I made , stupid from me , I would upvote your answer but someone give me a -1 so I can't :D hahaha but still thank you!!

Comment: As long as your got your answer :) I'm not sure how the accept answer works. Usually there's an accept marking under the arrows to your left side.

Comment: Oh well thank you , never knew that before , and now I could and did gave you a upvote :D and the accept answer! hahaha

Comment: Hehe perfect! :) Good luck